# Slow C# Graphics update for controls

Tags: c#, performance, graphics

I'm trying to understand how to speed up some graphical controls updates.  When there are large numbers of controls on a screen, the updates happen slow as shown in the example below.  How can I speed this up so that it updates all the controls at the same time with a 50ms update rate specified in the timer?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace FormTestApplication
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
    Timer t = new Timer();
    private Boolean flag = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Label l = new Label();
                l.Top = j * 30;
                l.Left = i * 25 + 20;
                l.BackColor = Color.Red;
                l.Width = 20;
                labels.Add(l);

            }
        }

        foreach (var label in labels)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(label);
        }

        t.Interval = 50;
        t.Tick += t_Tick;
        t.Start();

    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var label in labels)
        {
            if (label.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                label.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                label.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Maybe split the form up in multiple sections each with their own class/update handler/thread? Some tips: https://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=361

Comment: The Windows message loop plumbing adds a great deal of constant overhead on each dispatched message.  Right now you are hoping that it can deliver 20 x 20 x 2 x 1000 / 50 = 16000 messages per second.  As you found out, it can't, your UI thread is burning 100% core.  You'll have to stay well south of 5000 to get acceptable perf.  You must write smarter code, all of this can be done with a single paint instead of 800.   Whether you do this with a Paint event or use, say, ListView or DataGridView is up to you, the code is too fake to give specific advice.

Comment: How do I manually handle the On Paint to reduce the painting to 1 paint?

Comment: Hans,  can you please attempt to give specific advice for this example?  I would really appreciate an example showing how I override the paint and reduce messages.